# Cant extract arguments from my firebase callable function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

logging the form data i.e email, password and role, shows that correct data is being passed to the function

**App.js file**

```
 const createUserWithRole = httpsCallable(functions, "createUserAndAddUserRole"); 
 console.log(form) // WORKS
 const response = await createUserWithRole({
    email: form.email,
    password: form.password,
    role: form.role,
   });
```

**Functions.js**

```
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");

    // const cors = require("cors")({origin: true}); // Add cors middleware
    const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
    const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
    
    admin.initializeApp();
    exports.createUserAndAddUserRole = onCall(async (data, context) => {
      
      // logger 1
      logger.log("data", data);
    
      
      // const email = "bright@gmail.com";
      // const password = "bright";
      // const role = "admin";
    
      const userRecord = await admin
          .auth()
          .createUser({
            email,
            password,
          });
      logger.log("User Record", userRecord);
      return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then((user)=> {
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
          role: role,
        });
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("Claims Set");
        const userDataAfter = admin.getUserByEmail(data.email);
        return {
          status: 200,
          message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made ${data.role} role`,
        };
      }).catch((err) => {
        return {
          status: 500,
          message: err,
        };
      });
    });
```

running logger 1 prints out an object that seems to be a request object with the data I passed being under a subObject ***jsonPayload.data***

The documentation for onCall directs that simply using data.email will work but that doesnt work.

Am i passing the data wrong? How do i pass the data or extract it from the jsonPayload.data object?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the exact logs you see.  Copy the text directly out of whatever you're looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Cloud Functions 2n gen (cf. `const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");`). As you can see in the doc for [Callable Cloud Functions 2nd generation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd) the arguments passed to the callback function have changed from

`onCall((data, context) => {...});` (1st gen)

to

`onCall((request) => {...});` (2nd gen)

So you need to do as follows:

```js
exports.createUserAndAddUserRole = onCall(async (request) => {
      
   const email = request.data.email;
   const password = request.data.password;
   const role = request.data.role;

   // ...
```

Comment: Thanks. works. Had v2 onCall imported but was using v1 method of extracting data